# android save chats to sqlite db and retrieve them

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am developing a messaging app. Searched many tutorials for how to save chat/text messages to **sqlite** and retrieve it when the activity is created again. My code is like this -

This is `Chats.java`,

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chats, container, false);
        random = new Random();
        msg_text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        msgListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.msgListView);
        ImageButton sendButton = (ImageButton) view
                .findViewById(R.id.sendMessageButton);
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        msgListView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        msgListView.setStackFromBottom(true);
        chatlist = new ArrayList<ChatMessage>();
        chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getActivity(), chatlist);
        msgListView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    }

    public void sendTextMessage(View v) {
        String message = msg_edittext.getEditableText().toString();
        if (!message.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            final ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(user1, user2,
                    message, "" + random.nextInt(1000), true);
            chatMessage.setMsgID();
            chatMessage.body = message;
            chatMessage.Date = CommonMethods.getCurrentDate();
            chatMessage.Time = CommonMethods.getCurrentTime();
            msg_edittext.setText("");
            chatAdapter.add(chatMessage);
            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            MessengerActivity activity = ((MessengerActivity) getActivity());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sendMessageButton:
                sendTextMessage(v);

        }
    }
```

In `ChatAdapter.java`,

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ChatMessage message = (ChatMessage) chatMessageList.get(position);
        View vi = convertView;
        if (message.isMine) {
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_a);
            parent_layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        // If not mine then align to left
        else {
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_b);
            parent_layout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
}
```

How to save chats to sqlite db and retrieve when it is opened.

Comment: you can use realm also. It is alternative of sqlite in android.Realm is fast in retrieve and save data. please refer this link http://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: My question is how do I save... Irrespective of sqlite or realm

Comment: please read realm document.I can help you not teach you or do some googling on save data in sqlite in android.

Comment: The answer is totally irrelevant.. It doesnt matter I use realm or sqlite. All my problem is how to do it in sqlite. Reading realm doc would provide me knowledge but thats not what I need urgently!!!!

Comment: you way of answering is irrelevant.we can just provide way for you question not satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some good starting points on creating SQLite databases. Read them first and then have a go on your own:

[SQLite OpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)

[SQLite Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

[Saving Data in SQLite Database](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

There are tons more of examples online. I suggest reading the 3rd link first and then the rest.